# Implementation of hash table using unordered_map in c++ and handling collisions

Tags: c++, hash, stl, hashmap, unordered-map

How to implement a hash map using unordered map in c++.
If the keys in unordered map corresponds to the index generated by the hashing function,
what when there are multiple values have same keys( collision). Then how do we access these values using the same keys.

eg

```
unordered_map <int,string> hashTable;

hashTable.insert(pair<int,string>(3,"ab"))
hashTable.insert(pair<int,string>(3,"ba"))
```

Now how do access "ba"?

Comment: Unordered_map IS a hash table actually.

Comment: You may want to use a better example as, as is the second insert will fail since it has the same key.

Comment: This is exactly what my doubt is @amchacon, as the keys in an unordered_map must be unique and the hash keys are if indeed the keys of the unordered_map, then how will any collision be handled?

Comment: Lets say i want to store numbers for mod 7. So both 6 and 13 have same mod I'll have to do hash.insert(6,6) and hash.insert(6,13). But if I do this how do I access 13 in O(1) on average (since there is collision).So instead if I do hash.insert(6,6) and hash.insert(13,6) there will be no collision though but then it means that my unordered map will never be able to handle any collisions.

Answer (score 4):

As @amchacon pointed out, an std::unordered_map is already a hash table.

There is a difference between a key and hash(key). In an unordered_map, keys must be distinct, while hash of keys may collide. Take a closer look at the template parameters of [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). There is a Hash and there is a KeyEqual.

If you indeed want to have multiple records with the same key, use [std::unordered_multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap) instead.

Comment: So the value in the unordered_map is used as a key for the hash table it is actually implementing and the keys of the unordered_map is actually what we want to store?

Comment: You have to examine your data to see if it is indeed a collection of (key, value) pairs. E.g. if you have (int employee_id, string employee_info), you may store them into an unordered_map<int, string>. Normally you don't need to worry about "key for the hash table"; by default std::unordered_map uses std::hash<your key type>. On the other hand, you may have a collection of values. In this case, you could use an std::set instead. With that, the answer to your question is no; the value in the unordered_map is not used as a key for the hash table. std::hash<your key> is.

Answer (score 0):

`hashTable[3]` is "ba" actually.

you can search it like.

```
auto it = hashTable.find(3);
if(it!=hashTable.end()){
   std::cout << "item found" << it->second << "\n";
}else{
   std::cout << "item does not exists in table.";
}
```